# Why is "difference" used following "is"?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, complements

Could anyone please explains to me when to use "different" and when to use "difference"?

I searched the web about that and I have seen that difference is a noun and different is an adjective and for Comparison we use the noun form and for describing a person we use the adjective form of this word.

But I'm watching a TV show ([The 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_100_(TV_series))) on Netflix and I have heard them saying

> All the other clans have chosen there people and sky crow is no difference

So why they used the noun form instead of the adjective form? I'm still confused about when I use *different* and when I use *difference* in my daily life.

Comment: It must be *The 100*, since "sky crow" here sufficiently resembles *Skaikru*.  In this series many people born on the ground are native speakers of *Trigedasleng*, the language of the forest clan.  Grounder diction isn't intended to depict contemporary English usage.  There are Grounders that learn English as a dead language called *Gonasleng*.  *Skaikru* itself, the former residents of Ark Station, do speak American English natively.

Comment: Another user provided the name of the show, so I included it in post. Providing the source is important since it can reveal relevant details. It's also helpful to include a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that their usage is nonstandard. I am not familiar with the show, but sometimes characters in fiction are depicted as using incorrect language. Sometimes this is intentional, possibly to show that they are uneducated, that English is not their first language, or that they are using a different dialect from Standard English. At other times this can just be a mistake on the part of the creator or the person in charge of subtitles.

There are a couple more mistakes in the sentence you quoted. The correct sentence would be:

> All the other clans have chosen their people, and sky crow is no different.